# show image with popup

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hei
I Have this code, to take the pictures from a folder and show them on the page. But when I click on the image, it will open on the same page. So I have to click one page back...
But i wanna that when I cklick on a n image, that the image open with a popup and I can click there "back or next" to see the other images.
What I Have to change in the code?

Thanks a lot

```
<div id="galima">
  <?php
    $folder_path = 'gallery/images_nature/'; //image's folder path
     $num_files = glob($folder_path . "*.{JPG,jpg,gif,png,bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);
     $folder = opendir($folder_path);

        if($num_files > 0)
           {
            while(false !== ($file = readdir($folder))) 
                 {
                   $file_path = $folder_path.$file;
                   $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($file ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if($extension =='jpg' || $extension =='png' || $extension == 'gif' || $extension == 'bmp') 
           {
      ?>
       <a href="<?php echo $file_path; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $file_path; ?>" height="250"></a>

 <?php
      }
    }
 }
  else
    {
       echo "the folder was empty !";
    }
   closedir($folder);
 ?>
```

Comment: you tagged as javascript, so yeah... you need that; where's the code/attempt you made? there's a lot of stuff out there already, have you not found any?

Comment: *"with a popup and I can click there "back or next""* - You're looking for pagination. Look up "image on pop up with pagination javascript php". You will get many results, I'm sure. Edit: Possibly add on "ajax/jquery" to that search.

Comment: might want to check out highslide or something simular?

Comment: What you are looking for is called lightbox

Answer (score 0):

What you need is named `Lightbox` but 
here i am giving a simple example of creating new window in js. May be this will give you a better understanding to implement it in your code.

copy this code into any html file and see the output. i don't know why i can't 
add it in code snippet -_-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="">
            <img src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31300000/beautiful-heart-pic-beautiful-pictures-31395948-333-500.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="Click to enlarge"
            onclick="enlarge(this)" />
        </a>
        <a href="">
            <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/0e/38/60/0e38604bb8c49acf8eb409dc5f9caa15.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="Click to enlarge" onclick="enlarge(this)" />
        </a>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var windowFeatures = "'menubar=no,status=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,width=500,height=350,left=400,top=100'";

        function enlarge(x)  {
            window.open(
                x.src,
                'largeimage',
                windowFeatures
                );
        }
    </script>
    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

you can open the image in a new page using target _blank like this

```
<a href="<?php echo $file_path; ?>" target="_blank">...</a>
```